# Good place to start to find out how to fix Belarc Advisor Security Errors?

Tags: windows-7, security

I ran Belarc Advisor today on a machine and was shocked to see that the machine had a 1.25 out of 10 in the System Security Status.  There are sooo many errors that I don't even know where to begin.

Is there a guide anywhere on how to get started fixing these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed some of the errors that Belarc identifies.  As an example:

```
  Windows Firewall Inbound Rules  Section Score: 0.00 of 0.63  
 1.  Core Networking - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP-In) (CCE-14986)  
 2.  Core Networking - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCPV6-In) (CCE-14854)
```

If you aren't doing IPv6 in your network, and you have it disabled in Win7, worrying about IPv6 will be a waste of time.  Others, like:

```
 35.  Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts (CCE-9249)  
 36.  Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts and shares (CCE-9156)
```

If you do one, you do the other.  However there is a reason these are seperated.  You need to know when it's a good idea to apply this to both SAM accounts and shares.  Still other examples:

```
 26.  Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always) (CCE-9327)  
 27.  Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (if server agrees) (CCE-9344)
```

If you do one, you can't be doing the other (If you are ALWAYS signing something, you aren't doing it only if the server agrees).

Don't let this sacre you.  If you click on each item one at a time, they explain what they are, and what you need to do with them.

Remember that if you are using IE9 on windows:

> US Government OMB-mandated security configuration for Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 8.

Last, you asked about a guide, there really isn't one (that I've found or heard of), each item hyperlinks to an explanation about it.

Comment: Okay well it kinda set me off, thanks for your reply, I didn't know that some of them were mutually exclusive.